# Sudden .htaccess parsing error: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good morning and day!

Out of the blue my website (shared hosting) went down this morning with the 500 Internal Server Error. Checking the server logs, I found many copies of the following error:

```
[Wed Jun 08 8:44:17 2022] [core:alert] [pid 37935:tid 139960812291840] [client 172.71.94.83:22980] /usr/www/users/XXX/.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^([A-Za-z]{2})\\/([[:alnum:]-\\/\\.]+)$'
```

The actual line in .htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})\/([[:alnum:]-\/\.]+)$ $2 [L]
```

I removed the line and this brought the website back online, however I remember the line is needed somewhere along the way, and the website as of right now certainly malfunctions somewhere.

Does anyone know how to fix this regular expression? More interestingly, how could it have worked fine all those years?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Why are normal forward slashes escaped with a backslash? That should not be necessary; and since the message from the log shows the escaping backslashes _doubled_, I suppose it could have something to do with that.

Comment: That sounds like a small bug on the logging software side. The real issue was the misplaced hyphen (see the answer below).

Comment: What OS are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})\/([[:alnum:]-\/\.]+)$ $2 [L]
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯^
```

Later versions of the PCRE engine (that is used by Apache) will break at the range specifier (hyphen) after the POSIX character class (that indicates more than 1 letter). I assume this is intended to match a literal hyphen (as it would do in earlier versions of PCRE), in which case it should be at the start or end of the character class to avoid ambiguity.

This regex can also be "simplified" in a number of ways (and personally, I would avoid the POSIX character class).

- In the rule as stated you do not need the first capturing group. (Are there any *conditions* - `RewriteCond` directives - that precede this rule?)
- No need to backslash-escape slashes.
- No need to backslash-escape literal dots when used inside a character class.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]{2}/([a-zA-Z0-9/.-]+)$ $1 [L]
```

Note that having removed the first capturing group, the *substitution* becomes `$1`, not `$2`.

`[:alnum:]` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Or just use `\w` (word character) if you are OK with matching underscores (`_`) as well.

If there are preceding *conditions* that reference the `$1` backreference then you will need to add back the first parenthesised subpattern and adjust the *substitution* string accordingly. ie.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9/.-]+)$ $2 [L]
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank for you much. You solved my problem, explained it all and improved my regex.